# Teradata remove enclosing single quotes from variable

Tags: teradata, quotes

I need to replace single quotes in a string of numbers and use in a WHERE IN clause. for example, I have

```
WHERE Group_ID IN (''4532','3422','1289'')
```

The criteria within parenthesis is being passed as a parameter, so I have no control over that. I tried using :

```
WHERE Group_ID IN (REGEXP_REPLACE(''4532','3422','1289'', '[']', ' ',1,0,i))
```

also tried using OReplace

```
WHERE Group_ID IN (OReplace(''4532','3422','1289'', '[']', ' '))
```

but get the same error:

```
[Teradata Database] [3707] Syntax error, expected something like ',' 
    between a string or a Unicode character literal and the integer '4532'.
```

Please suggest how to remove the single enclosing quotes or even removing all single quotes should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The string `''4532','3422','1289''` you are using is incorrect because it contains non-escaped single quotes. This is a syntax error in SQL. In this particular form, no matter what function you use to fix it or which RDBMS you use, it will result in error with standard SQL.

Functions in the SQL cannot fix syntax errors. `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `OReplace` never get executed because the query never enters the execution state. It never goes past the SQL syntax parser.

To see the error from perspective of the SQL parser, you may break the string in to multiple parts

1. `''` -- SQL Parser sees this as a starting and ending quote and hence an empty string
2. `4532` -- Now comes what appears to SQL parser as an integer value
3. `','` -- Now this is a pair of quotes containing a single comma
4. `3422` -- Again an integer
5. `','` -- Again a comma
6. `1289` -- Again integer
7. `''` -- Again emtpy string

This amalgam of strings and numbers will not mean anything to the SQL parser and will result in an error.

### Fix

The fix is to properly escape the data. Single quotes must be escaped using another preceding single quote. So correct string in this scenario becomes `'''4532'',''3422'',''1289'''`

---

Another thing is that the `OReplace` usage (once syntax is fixed) is like `OReplace(yourStringValueHere, '''', ' '))` Observe the usage of escaped single quote here. Two outer quotes are for the string start and end. First inner quote is the escape character and second inner quote is the actual data passed to the function.